# Converting regex from ruby to PHP

Tags: php, ruby, regex

I have been trying to convert a regular expression from ruby to PHP, however I have had little luck.

This is the ruby regular expression:

```
QUOTED_LITERAL = /"[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*"/
UNQUOTED_LITERAL = /[^\s=,][^\s=,\\]*(?:\\.[^\s=,\\]*|=[^,>])*/
LITERAL = /(#{QUOTED_LITERAL}|#{UNQUOTED_LITERAL})/
PAIR = /#{LITERAL}\s*=>\s*#{LITERAL}/
```

And this is my go in PHP:

```
 const PAIR = '/("[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*"|[^\s=,][^\s=,\\]*(?:\\.[^\s=,\\]*|=[^,>])*)\s*=>\s*("[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*"|[^\s=,][^\s=,\\]*(?:\\.[^\s=,\\]*|=[^,>])*)/';
```

However when I run

```
$result = preg_match_all(self::PAIR, $input, $matches);
```

I get the error:

`preg_match_all(): Compilation failed: unmatched parentheses at offset 62`

---

However when run it through, http://www.phpliveregex.com/ with the test data:

```
"foo" => "bar", "foo" => bar, foo => "bar"
```

it seems to work fine.

Not sure whats going on.

Comment: What's your version of PHP? Just do "php --version"

Comment: It is php 5.5.1. Living on the edge!

Comment: I've had several problems with php's preg_match in 5.4.2+. You might try a lower version, might fix your problem.

Comment: @adrian - Really? preg uses the same regexp library that most other programming languages (including ruby) do. I find it hard to believe that it should be buggy.

Comment: On infoarena.ro we use textile which relies on preg a lot. We've had the problem with a few versions of it on one particular page, though I can't remember exactly which one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### The problem lies with your backslashes.

I managed to get it to compile after removing all backslashes.

Then, I replaced all double slashes with 4 of them, and `preg_match_all()` was able to compile the regex too.

```
const PAIR = '/("[^"\\\\]*(?:\\\\.[^"\\\\]*)*"|[^\s=,][^\s=,\\\\]*(?:\\\\.[^\s=,\\\\]*|=[^,>])*)\s*=>\s*("[^"\\\\]*(?:\\\\.[^"\\\\]*)*"|[^\s=,][^\s=,\\\\]*(?:\\\\.[^\s=,\\\\]*|=[^,>])*)/';
```

You might have to edit it to get the exact regex you want. You had the compilation error because `\\` was fed to the regex engine as `\`, which escaped the immediate square brackets. To encode a literal backslash, you need to use `\\\\` - once for the string, and once for the regex engine.

```
string '\\\\'  --becomes--> regex \\ --becomes--> literal \
```

Ruby doesn't have this problem because its regex syntax is separate from its string syntax.

(Related question: [preg_match(): Compilation failed: unmatched parentheses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10384843/preg-match-compilation-failed-unmatched-parentheses-in-php-for-valid-patte).)